# Clearing xcom data with dag_id and execution_date

Tags: airflow

I am trying to clear xcom values based on the execution_date older than 30 days, but the dag is throwing error as execution date is not defined . Please help to understand the issue here (airflow 2.4.3)

code is follows

```
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.utils.db import provide_session
from airflow.models import XCom
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from airflow.operators.dummy import DummyOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from datetime import datetime, timedelta,timezone
from sqlalchemy import func

with DAG(dag_id="cleanup_xcom_demo", schedule_interval=None, start_date=days_ago(2)) as dag:
    # cleanup_xcom
    @provide_session
    def cleanup_xcom(session=None, **context):
        dag = context["dag"]
        dag_id = dag._dag_id 
        # It will delete all xcom of the dag_id
        ts_limit = datetime.now(timezone.utc) - timedelta(days=30)
        print(f"printing session {session}")
        session.query(XCom).filter(Xcom.execution_date <= ts_limit ).delete()
   
    clean_xcom = PythonOperator(
        task_id="clean_xcom",
        python_callable = cleanup_xcom,
        provide_context=True, 
        # dag=dag
    )
    
    start  = DummyOperator(task_id="start")
    end = DummyOperator(task_id="end", trigger_rule="none_failed")
    
    start >> clean_xcom >> end
```

here is the error

```
Xcom is not defined 

when i remove xcom from xcom.execution_date and keep only execution_date in filter then it throws error as execution_date not defined
```

Comment: If this is wrong, I'll take a much closer look to understand and give you a better response, but if you didn't change the case on your error (nor your code), I think you just have a typo: `.filter(Xcom.execution_date` should be `.filter(XCom.execution_date`

Again, could be completely wrong, but that might be all it is. I'll keep looking anyway to see what else might be wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I replaced the `session.query` as below and the error went away:

```
session.query(XCom).filter(XCom.execution_date <= ts_limit).delete(synchronize_session='fetch')
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on [@Evan Fiddler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6772160/evan-fiddler) 's answer, `Xcom`=>`XCom` is the biggest problem,
I also find some tiny problems:

1. For Airflow>=2.0 no need to use `provide_context`. Airflow already handles it.
2. For Airflow>=2.3.0, `DummyOperator` was deprecated, you should use `EmptyOperator`:

```
from airflow.operators.empty import EmptyOperator
```

3. For Airflow>=2.2.5, you should use `XCom.timestamp` rather than `XCom.execution_date`, if you still think execution time is not precise enough, you could seperate execution_date from run_id
4. For me, I highly suggest you to use `logical_date` instead of `datetime.now()`

```
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.utils.db import provide_session
from airflow.models import XCom
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from airflow.operators.empty import EmptyOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from datetime import timedelta

with DAG(dag_id="cleanup_xcom_demo", schedule_interval=None, start_date=days_ago(2)) as dag:

    @provide_session
    def cleanup_xcom(session=None, logical_date=None, **context):
        dag = context["dag"]
        dag_id = dag._dag_id
        ts_limit = logical_date - timedelta(days=30)
        session.query(XCom).filter(XCom.timestamp <= ts_limit).delete()

    clean_xcom = PythonOperator(
        task_id="clean_xcom",
        python_callable=cleanup_xcom,
        dag=dag
    )

    start = EmptyOperator(task_id="start")
    end = EmptyOperator(task_id="end", trigger_rule="none_failed")

    start >> clean_xcom >> end
```